# refresh a same page without reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I have already asked this question here but none of the answers were working. I have a messaging app in Django where users can send messages each other. I want to refresh the page so that the user can see new messages. But there is one problem if the user is writing a message and I try to reload the page every x-minutes the message that the user was writing will disapear. So how can I avoid this?

```
/*This is one of the solutions that I have tried*/
window.location.reload(true);
history.go(0);
window.location.href=window.location.href;
```

messages.html:

```
{% extends 'profile/base.html' %}
{% load tz %}
{% block title %}
Messages
{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
          #form {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color:#f1f1f1;
          }
.container {
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 1px 0;
}


.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.darker {
  border-color: #ccc;
  background-color:#ddd;
}

.container img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 40px;
  height:40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.time-left {
  margin-left:61px;
  color: #999;
}

h4 {
    display:inline;
}
    </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% if not chat %}
    <div class="container">
         Impossible de commencer un chat avec cet utilisateur ou bien vous n'avez pas acces a ce chat.
    </div>
{% else %}
    {% if chat %}
        <div id ='bottom' class="panel">
                {% for message_item in chat.message_set.all %}
                {% url 'profile' message_item.author.pk as the_user_url%}
    {% if message_item.is_readed %}
    <div class="container">
    {% else %}
    <div class="container darker">
    {% endif %}
    <a href="{{ the_user_url }}">

  <img src="{{ message_item.author.profile.avatar.url }}" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;">
  <h4><a href="{{ the_user_url }}">{{ message_item.author.profile.prenom|title }}</a></h4>
  <p>{{ message_item.message }}</p>
  <span class="time-left">{{ message_item.pub_date|utc }}</span>
  </a>
</div>

                {% endfor %}
                <br><br><br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <div class='w3-container'>
    <div id='form'>
        <form method="post" action='{% url 'messages' chat.id %}'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}

            <input type="submit" value='envoyez' />
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $('document').ready(function() {
           $('html').animate({scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight},1);
        });
        </script>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('dialogs/<int:chat_id>/',views.MessagesView.as_view(), name='messages'),
    ]
```

Comment: you can use ajax to refresh the messages, or use session to svae a messages.

Comment: If you're writing a messaging system, look in to using Websockets. That way you avoid the problem of refreshing the page causing the content the user was typing to be lost, and also avoids the need for AJAX polling which will cause server performance issues.

Comment: @ming  i am new in django and web developpement and for now i just need to use  ajax can anyone give me an idea how to do it in ajax or using sessions

Comment: Just search regarding ajax and JavaScript, this site does not replace relevant documentation and tutorials but it is for concise questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a messaging app, it's better to not reload the page, instead use Ajax/fetch and just call your get-messages request, then show messages in the page,
for example:

```js
const getMessages = ()=>{
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments") // use your messages request url, this is a sample
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((messages) => {
    let messagesHtml = "";
    for (var message of messages) {
    
      messagesHtml += `<div>${message.name}</div>`; // use your message html structure here
    }

    let messagesContainer = document.getElementById("messagesContainer");
    messagesContainer.innerHTML = messagesHtml;
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

  
  setInterval(getMessages, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="messagesContainer"></div>
```

If you have to reload the page, you can check the last time that user was typing and reload the page with a delay,
for example listen to keypress and set a variable that you can handle page reload with that:

```js
reloadDelay = 0;
function setDelayForReload(){
  reloadDelay = 3000;
}

function reloadPage(){
if(reloadDelay == 0){
  window.location.reload()
}

}
setTimeout(reloadPage, 3000)
```

```html
<body onkeypress="setDelayForReload()">
  <div id="messagesContainer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer  and it is a very good idea i have tried it but it does not solve my problem.i think the solution will be using ajax.

Comment: Your welcome, Yes you can use first snippet I provided, fetch acts same as ajax and it's much simpler!

Comment: You need to call your url in the fetch ("dialogs/<int:chat_id>"), then in the response, as I see in your code, you will have all the data( like is_readed, author,...) that you have in message_item in the `message` variable in fetch response, so you can use them and create the same html structure that you have for your message, and add it's html to your message container (you need to have a div for your messages with an html id and use it)

Answer (score 1):

That would more likely be something like this:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES);    }?>" name="username">
```

Make sure you escape any data before echoing it to the browser (as per the above example) – otherwise, what would happen if the user entered a " into the username box?

Comment: @amadousow You have used the html tag in your question, due to which I posted this answer. Sorry if I could’nt help

Answer (score 1):

It is called web 2.0 and you don't need to load a page again.
The most interactive pages have only 1 page and everything is then loaded in background.

You can then deliver your page as Pwa for example.

To get the contents of another page, you should use the fetch() function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

It returns a promise. In this way you don't need to set any callback.

Comment: thanks for your answer can you give me a simple example ?

Comment: @amadousow in the link there are many examples. You can just change the content of a div or you can also set the entire body with document.body.innerHTML=fetchedContent. (but this is not a good way to update something)

Comment: can i show you my html file or if you have time i can make a chat so we can discuss please

Comment: @amadousow akram wrote a nice example with fetch. I am on the phone, so I can't write an example now. If you are a guru, you can use push notification. So you have an immediate forward and you don't need to poll. But it doesn't work on every browser.

Comment: @ Adriano i have transformed my web site in to mobile app using GOnative.i never used Fetch so ...

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple ways to achieve this

1. save the content of the input field where the user is typing into
   local storage and after reloading the page repopulate that input field
2. use Ajax to check whether more messages are created and just
   populate the messages without reloading anything.
3. use services like firebase or pusher. it can be used to get Async
   updates when you get new messages
4. use socket programming to get updates and only change the relevant
   part of dom

Comment: thanks for your answer i really want to use 2) but i do not know how .